# Error in adding a mongoDb cartridge to OpenShift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

The process of adding a mongoDb (2.4) cartridge to my OpenShift application seems to work fine but ends up with an error and no cartridge is added. It looks like a disk space problem (I have already mysql in the same application), but I freed plenty of space and, strangely enough, the problem only appears at the very end of setup. Here is the log (hiding login details):

```
Starting MongoDB cartridge
note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
Sat May  3 19:38:54.847 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=389973 port=2701
dbpath=/var/lib/openshift/5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a/mongodb/data/ 64-bit host=ex-std-node94.prod.rhcloud.com
Sat May  3 19:38:54.848 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Sat May  3 19:38:54.848 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat May  3 19:38:54.848 [initandlisten] build info: Linux x86-023.build.eng.bos.redhat.com 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 5 21:21:44 EDT 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Sat May  3 19:38:54.849 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Sat May  3 19:38:54.849 [initandlisten] options: { auth: true, bind_ip: "127.2.148.131", config: "/tmp/mongodb.repair.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/openshift/5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a/mongodb/data/", nohttpinterface: "true", noprealloc: "true", pidfilepath: "/var/lib/openshift/5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a/mongodb/pid/mongodb.pid", quiet: "true", repair: true, smallfiles: "true" }
************** 
You specified --repair but there are dirty journal files. Please
restart without --repair to allow the journal files to be replayed.
If you wish to repair all databases, please shutdown cleanly and
run with --repair again.
**************
Sat May  3 19:38:54.865 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 12596 old lock file,    terminating
Sat May  3 19:38:54.866 dbexit: 
Sat May  3 19:38:54.866 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat May  3 19:38:54.866 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat May  3 19:38:54.867 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat May  3 19:38:54.867 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat May  3 19:38:54.867 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat May  3 19:38:54.867 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat May  3 19:38:54.868 dbexit: really exiting now
Warning: Gear 5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a is using 98.9% of disk quota
Warning: Gear 5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a is using 97.3% of disk quota
Attempting to repair MongoDB ...

MongoDB 2.4 database added.  Please make note of these credentials:

Root User:     ------------
Root Password: ------------
Database Name: ------------

Connection URL: mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/
Failed to execute: 'control start' for   /var/lib/openshift/5c0013917b4d45c68fddbb75e082a35a/mongodb
```

Any idea on how to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the logs it looks like you have consumed most of your 1GB disk space. The 1 GB disk space is consumed by all your application cartridges and storage.Which web cartridge are you using? Can you check the disk space usage using `quota -s` command. SSH into the application gear and run `quota -s` command. Or if you have rhc command-line installed then you can use `rhc ssh --app <app_name> --command 'quota -s'`. You can clean up disk space using `rhc tidy --app <app_name>` command.  After cleaning up, try running rhc cartridge command again. You can create a scalable application and that would allow every cartridge to be installed on a different gear. This would allow each cartridge more disk space.